# Angular RXJS structuring observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a FeatureToggle guard that calls a FeatureToggle service to get an array of feature toggles, but I am struggling to get my head around how to structure the observables similar to how I would do it with promises.

guard -

```
canActivate() {
   if(this.toggleService.hasToggles){
      return this.toggleService.isOn('my toggle');
   } else {
      return this.toggleService.getToggles().subscribe(() => {
         return this.toggleService.isOn('my toggle')
      })
   }
}
```

service -

```
@Injectable    
export class ToggleService {
       private _toggles: string[];
       private _hasToggles: boolean;

       getToggles() {
          return this.http.get('...').subscribe((toggles) => {
             this._toggles = toggles;
          })
       }

       isOn(toggle) {
          // return if toggle is in this._toggles;
       }
    }
```

However because inside the service I am already subscribing, what I would be returning is a subscription, not an observable.  I can create a local reference to the observable in `getToggles` and return that, but is that the pattern I should be using?

Comment: The service should return the observable: `getToggles() { return this.http.get(...); }`.

Comment: i was hoping for the service to be injectable, that would maintain the list of toggles for other parts of the app to use?

Comment: I don't understand why you have to subscribe inside your guard. It seems like you could just use `map(() => this.toggleService.isOn('my toggle'))` and return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Observables, there is always the edge where you cannot pass an `Observable` any further. In Angular they can be passed into as far as the view template, subscribing to them via the `| async` pipe. Or, in your case, as the returned value of the `canActivate`. Therefore it is very handy to use Observables in your service.

In you service, if you want to cache the results, you could store them using `BehaviourSubject` and then pass them further as Observable. Or you could create an observable with `shareReplay` operator and re-use it. Or, simply, you could just store them away and return them using the `of` function from `'rxjs'`. I'm going to illustrate the last option.

```
@Injectable    
export class ToggleService {
   private _toggles: string[];
   private _hasToggles: boolean;

   getToggles(refresh?: boolean) {
      if (!refresh || !this.toggles) {
      return this.http.get('...').pipe(
        tap((toggles) => {
         this._toggles = toggles;
        });
      );
      } else {
        return of(this._toggles);
      }

   }
```

From the `isOn` you can also return an `Observable` - of `boolean` type. That way you can pass it as far as possible.

```
   isOn(toggle): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.getToggles().pipe(
        map(toggles => toggles.includes(toggle))
      )
   }
```

The `canActivate` becomes very simple:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.toggleService.isOn('my toggle');
}
```

Angular subscribes to the returned observable. There's no need to check whether the toggles have already been loaded - the service already takes care of that.

Comment: i think this is pretty much what im looking for, `tap` providing a way of having side effects whilst passing the observable along.  I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: @cgTag's answer also illustrates the other two options, which may look harder to understand but are cleaner in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ReplaySubject` to repeat the last emitted values for new subscriptions, and then have `getToggles()` call `http.get()` only once.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/replaysubject.html

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ToggleService {
    private _toggles: ReplaySubject<string[]>;

    getToggles(): ReplaySubject<string[]> {
        if (!this._toggles) {
            this._toggles = new ReplaySubject();
            this.http.get('...').subscribe((toggles) => this._toggles.next(toggles));
        }
        return this._toggles;
    }

    isOn(toggle): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.getToggles().pipe(map(toggles => toggles.includes(toggle)));
    }
}
```

You can also use a `shareReply` operator:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ToggleService {
    private _toggles: Observable<string[]>;

    getToggles(): Observable<string[]> {
        if (!this._toggles) {
            this._toggles = this.http.get('...').pipe(shareReplay(1));
        }
        return this._toggles;
    }

    isOn(toggle): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.getToggles().pipe(map(toggles => toggles.includes(toggle)));
    }
}
```